# Hangfire loading jobs it cant execute

Tags: hangfire

ive just started on a project where hangfire is being used.
We have 2 different api's that register recurring jobs in a shared hangfire database. Now the problem is that both api's cannot execute all of these themselves as the implementation of the jobs is split between the 2 api's.
And so if you open the dashboard with recurring jobs you get an error for some jobs saying that the assembly for the implementation could not be found.

How can i make Hangfire only load the recurring jobs for which it has an implementation? I can't seem to find any information on this topic.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Ok so the answer was that you can do that using queues. However since both api's still have their own dashboard you would still see the recurringjobs from the other api.

In the end i decided to make each api use their own hangfire schema so they cannot see eachothers jobs.

```
services.AddHangfire(x => x.UseSqlServerStorage(_autConn, new SqlServerStorageOptions() { SchemaName = "Api1-Hangfire" }));
```